# ROR - getaddrinfo: No address associated with hostname (SocketError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, capistrano

I have rails 3.2.6 and ruby 1.9.3 application deployed with capistrano and getting this error.

I am getting **No address associated with hostname (SocketError)**

```
getaddrinfo: No address associated with hostname (SocketError)
/var/www/darmacorp/releases/20140512114414/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gelf-      1.4.0/lib/gelf/ruby_sender.rb:16:in `send'
/var/www/darmacorp/releases/20140512114414/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gelf-1.4.0/lib/gelf/ruby_sender.rb:16:in `block in send_datagrams'
```

I am system admin and got this while setting up ROR application and not sure if it has something to do with the server related like DNS issue or some bug or development issue.

Is this something related to configuration or application require some service that is not accessible on the server?

Can you please help what exactly is wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132525/getaddrinfo-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known?rq=1, here your answer.

Comment: In my case, I was using Postmark to send an email and they were having issues with their DNS. Difficult to diagnose that it was their fault, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132525/getaddrinfo-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known)