# 'getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known' for a Mandrill email signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, actionmailer, mandrill

I am using Mandrill API for managing action_mailer on my rails project. I was following a tutorial and doing everything right, when I should have gotten a confirmation. Instead I go this:

```
Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 26.2ms

Sent mail to X@gmail.com (520.8ms)
Date: Sat, 31 Oct 2015 14:48:35 -0400
From: "Goose @ VBooked" <no-reply@VBooked.com>
Reply-To: "Goose @ VBooked" <no-reply@VBooked.com>
To: X@gmail.com
Message-ID: <56350d0357710_3c0c3fd2af544f901078c@Carters-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome carter.marino@gmail.com!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=fFq8sRnP6fEsyWnGk8w1">Confirm my account</a></p>

   (2.8ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 646ms (ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)

SocketError (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known):
  /Users/Goose/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `initialize'
  /Users/Goose/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `open'
  /Users/Goose/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `tcp_socket'
  /Users/Goose/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:551:in `block in do_start'
  /Users/Goose/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:89:in `block in timeout'
  /Users/Goose/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:99:in `call'
  /Users/Goose/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
  /Users/Goose/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `do_start'
  /Users/Goose/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
  mail (2.6.3) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
  mail (2.6.3) lib/mail/message.rb:2141:in `do_delivery'
  mail (2.6.3) lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `block in deliver'
  actionmailer (4.2.4) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:543:in `block in     deliver_mail'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
```

activesupport (4.2.4)

Any idea how I can troubleshoot the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a Mandrill issue, but a DNS resolution problem. Try this link [getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132525/getaddrinfo-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known)

HTH,