# Why am I seeing this error, Ruby SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection

Tags: ruby, net-http

Right now I am currently running into this error message while making a simple GET request in ruby:

```
#<SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to api.github.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)>
```

This is my ruby code:

```rb
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

class RequestDouble
  def initialize(endpoint)
    @endpoint = endpoint
  end


  def send_get_request
    url = URI(endpoint)
    https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    https.use_ssl = true
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
    request['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    response = https.request(request)
    JSON.parse(response.read_body)
  rescue StandardError => e
    { 'status' => 500, 'detail' => 'Something went wrong' }
  end

  private


  attr_accessor :endpoint

end
```

And this is the execution of the request:

```
github_request = RequestDouble.new('https://api.github.com/repos/robskrob/personal-site')
github_request.send_get_request
```

Does anyone see why I'm getting the above `SocketError` message? Does anyone know how I can successfully make the GET request in ruby? This request `https://api.github.com/repos/robskrob/personal-site` works just fine in postman and in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I am not 100 percent certain as to why this worked but all I had to was turn my computer off and on. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132525/getaddrinfo-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known/4133272) navigated me to the decision. `curl` was working for me in making the request in my shell so there had to be something badly cached on the `ruby` side of things as it related to the network.